# Unable to print the statements after yylex

Tags: c, lex

I'm trying to count the total number of Upper and lower case characters in a lex program and the input is being taken forever without encountering an EOF in windows.
My first program in lex. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int Upper=0;
    int Lower=0;
%}
%%
[A-Z] {printf("Uppercase\t");Upper++;}
[a-z] {printf("Lowercase\t");Lower++;}

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    yylex();
    printf("Uppercase=%d and Lowercase=%d",Upper,Lower);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

As you can see I'm unable to print the Upper and Lower Counters. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Did you only press the `Enter` key, or the end-of-file key (`Ctrl-z` in Windows)? The lexing will only stop on end-of-file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried ctrl+z ctrl+d but they are just getting printed as ^Z and so on but isnt encountered as an EOF

Comment: Unfortunately on Windows you first of all have to press `Ctrl-z` on a new line, and secondly you might need to press `Enter` as well.